# TooManyRedirects when Trying to login to website via Pythons requests Package

Tags: python-3.x

Im tryning to login on a Website using Pyhthons requests Package. By inserting this example:

```
    login_url = 'URL'
    payload = {'username': username, 'password': password}

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
        print(p.text)

        url = "URL-where-i-need-to-be-logged-in"
        r = s.get(url)
        print(r.text)
```

I got the following Error:

```
  File "my_file", line 15, in download_faecher
    p = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 165, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: have you checked the URL manually? Too Many Redirects doesn't look like a client error. In principle, you could increase the number of allowed redirects but most likely you are caught in a redirection loop

Comment: @Raphael: I can manually go an that URL and login, Is there a tool or something to track what Firefox is doing while I log in? Maybe I can find the problem in that way.

Comment: chrome comes with a [network activity monitor](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network). For firefox I can't tell